# Libraray/Toolkit API: How to handle composition when containing objects are not known

Tags: java, database, api-design

Could not think of a good title.

I'm creating a library / toolkit for storing and searching a special kind of data (does not really matter to the question but it's chemical structures) in a database. the search function returns a list of compounds where a compound consist of 1 or more chemicals.

A developer using that toolkit can use it to create multiple applications that store compounds. The idea is that there should be only 1 store for all applications. As example lets say he creates an Inventory system in which each container contains a compound. He also creates an application for storing biological test results. We now have 2 classes (Container, BiologicalTestResult) which contain a Compound but the API has no knowledge of. What i want is when storing a compound the API should be able to store in which applications it occurs. So when searching in Application A, only compounds that actually are in application A are returned.

Also when searching the API should be capable of filtering by data specific to that application, eg. testResult = "Failed" or remainingAmount > 100.

What would be a good way to achieve that? I think the most easiest solution would be to build SQL statement by string concatenation (with associated downsides).  This would eliminate the need for the toolkit to store to which application it belongs. Example:

```
search(String searchTerm, String selectFields, String joinTable, Filter filter);
```

where "selectFields" is the fields to return from "joinTable", "joinTable" is the applications table containing a foreign key to the compound table and filter is a custom class that contains the "where clause", eg mapping field name to a condition (>,<, like, = ...)  and a value.

Is this reasonable? Better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to have a proper domain model and then you can work with QueryDSL.